# Access function of another processing js file

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I have two processing.js files both displayed on a webpage with the canvas tag. I would like to be able to pass a variable between those two programs periodically. I was looking around on how to do this and I found an answer here on stack overflow. It said to do this:

```
instance = Processing.getInstanceById('second');
instance.hi();
```

to run the hi function. I tried that and got an error. I was able to do other things like this:

```
instance.ellipse(50,50,10,10);
```

That made an ellipse on the other canvas like it is supposed to.

What did I do wrong? Any other things i could use? The error said this specifically:
TypeError: instance.hi is not a function. (In 'instance.hi()', 'instance.hi' is undefined)
(anonymous function)                                                                                           processing.js:2911


**EDIT**


The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Test</title>
<script src="processing.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<canvas data-processing-sources="get.pde"></canvas>
<p>test</p>
<canvas id ="source" data-processing-sources="source.pde"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

get.pde

```
void setup(){
size(200,200);
}


void mouseOver(){
instance = Processing.getInstanceById('source');
console.log(instance);
instance.hi();
}

void draw(){

ellipse(50,50,20,20);

}
```

source.pde

```
void setup(){
size(200,200);
}


var hi=function(){println("hello world");};

void draw(){

ellipse(20,20,10,10);

}
```

Comment: How are you defining your `hi()` function?

Comment: @KevinWorkman `var hi=function(){println("hello world");};`

Comment: And where is that line in your code? You'll have much better luck if you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @KevinWorkman I added my code to the question. The error # is 1699 instead of 2911.